# loop in R doesn't work

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am trying to loop over multiple time series in order to use seasonal package and while the code works just fine for individual series, the loop does not continue and I get something like this

```
    i = `i'+1
+ }
+
```

Any idea what's wrong in the code below? I would greatly appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

```
i=1
while i<=79 {
  rm(list=ls()) #clear workspace
  sad <- read.dta("C:/esample`i'.dta")
  sad <- data.frame(sad)
  ts<- lapply(sad,ts,frequency=12, start=1960.1) 
  l1 <- lapply(ts, function(e) try(seas(e, na.action = na.x13) ))
  is.err <- sapply(l1, class) == "try-error"
  d_sad <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(l1[!is.err], final)))
  save.image("C:/dsad`i'.RData")
  write.dta(d_sad, "X:/dsad`i'.dta")
  i = `i'+1
}
```

Comment: You remove the index `i`. I doubt it's necessary to clear the workspace at the start; but you might want to rm(sad, ts, ...) at the end. Alternately, you might want to wrap it in a function..

Comment: The local syntax for Stata (`\`i'`) does not carry over to R.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two issues from what I can see.

1.The while condition needs to be in brackets. e.g:

```
while(i <= 79) {...
```

2.The part where you advance the loop is incorrect, you have quotes (two different kinds actually, which is why it is asking for additional input) when you don't need any quotes. All you need is:

```
i = i + 1
```

Comment: They should use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. This worked:

```
    mywd=setwd
    i=1
    while (i<=20) {
      infile <- paste("esample",i,".dta",sep=""); 
outfileR<- paste("dsad",i,".RData",sep="")
      outfile <- paste("dsad",i,".dta",sep=""); 
      sad <- read.dta(infile)
      sad <- data.frame(sad)
      ts<- lapply(sad[-1],ts,frequency=12, start=1960.1)
      l1<- lapply(ts, function(e) try(seas(e, na.action = na.x13) ))
      # list failing models
      is.err <- sapply(l1, class) == "try-error"
      # return final series of successful evaluations
      d_sad1 <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(l1[!is.err], final)))
      write.dta(d_sad1, outfile)
      save.image(outfileR)
      rm(sad, ts, infile, outfileR, outfile, is.err, d_sad, d_sad1, l1) 
      i = i+1
    }
```